# What are my Keystore passwords when creating it using Visual Studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, keystore, sign

I'm trying to build a signed application using App Center.

[App center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M4Ho.png)

It asks me for 3 Environment variables, which I don't understand. I only get to write Alias and one password when creating Keystore file in Visual Studio as you can see in picture bellow.

[Visual studio create new Keystore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agkCX.png)

I'm probably missing private "Key password".

So what exactly I should put into these rows in App Center for successful signing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, you can try to input the same password of `keystore password` for  `Key password`.

[image]

Comment: Right, it did build thanks. I'll accept your answer, but maybe someone can explain why that is the case.